# What is dx.jar in the Android SDKs?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

What is the purpose of the dx.jar file that I see in some of Android SDK versions that I've installed with the Android SDK manager; the file appears under tools/lib/dx.jar I do NOT see the file in versions above android-8 and above. However Intellij IDEA gives an error when I try to build a project with android-8 and above, saying that dx.jar doesn't exist. What gives?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: dx.jar is part of the build process, used to convert Java bytecode into Dalvik bytecode. You will never see it in `android-8` or similar directories, as it is part of the tools, not part of an individual API level's SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare how do you konw that it is used to covert java class to dalvik bytecode?

Comment: @hugemeow: When you run the **`dx`** command, it says: "Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a jar/zip".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional to  CommonsWare's comment.

The dx.jar was original located under `android-sdk/platforms/android-X/tools/lib/` before (especially in android-3 and android-4), and moved to `android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/` later. Unfortunately this has never documented in any official source, probably because it is part of internal tools which Google doesn't want to consumer developer to be bothered. check out [this blog](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/android-developers/11ac4v8zdm/maven-dx-cant-find-dx-jar) to see the problem.

As long as you follow [Android installation guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents) and add android-sdk/tools/ and android-sdk/platform-tools/ to your PATH environment variable, you should be fine to access dx.jar, unless you use a really old Android SDK version (I doubt that).

Last, as a quick reference, this is command how SDK typically use dx.jar to dex you java bytecode with external jar libraries:

> [INFO] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\bin\java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar, --dex, --output=C:\workspace\myproject\target\classes.dex, C:\workspace\myproject\target\classes, C:\workspace\myprojec\libs\common-lib.jar, ... ...]

Answer (score 7):

Currently, `dx.jar` has been moved to

```
adt-bundle-*\sdk\build-tools\17.0.0\lib
```

You can find the source code of dx [here](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/tree/master/dx).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I do see several versions (different size files) of dx and dx.jar in the various android sdk version subdirectories. I had been managing the SDKs through Eclipse, which a few months ago changed in this regard (now with a separate SDK Manager window) - so perhaps things got screwed up somehow in that transition process...

Comment: dx is just a shell script used to run the lib/dx.jar.