# Where is the 'dx' tool located in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have installed the latest Android SDK just now.

But I can't find the **dx** tool (which is used to convert .class to .dex file). Neither under `platform-tool/` nor under `tools/`. Where can I find my **dx** tool then?

(With Android SDK Manager in Eclipse, I have installed **Android SDK Tools**, **Android SDK Platform Tools**, **Android SDK Build Tools**, and **All the Android platforms** from API 3 to API 19.)

Comment: adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk//build-tools/android-4.3/dx

Comment: Found it, but when I run dx under that path, I got "dx: command not found"

Comment: did you put a dot before? ./build-tools/android-4.3/dx

Comment: I am under android-4.3/

Comment: then you have to use ./dx ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, please make a formal answer, I will accept. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is dx.jar in the Android SDKs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456265/what-is-dx-jar-in-the-android-sdks)

Comment: The universal way (Linux) is run this command `find . -iname '*dx*'` to located a file recursively in current directory. That asterisks make it include similar name(since it might not startwiths dx) and possible extensions (e.g. dx.jar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dx` tool is located inside `build-tools/android-{version}`.

From the shell you can type `./dx` if you are inside the directory `android-{version}`, and the whole path to `dx` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I found it under "android-sdk\build-tools\any-sdk-build-tool-version".

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)? Can you provide an *example* of a *full* path? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30093757/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in *\platforms\any-platform\tools\dx.bat*.

Comment: I don't have tools/ folder under /platforms/any-platform/

Comment: This seems to be on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) (backslashes and the file extension "bat"). Can you provide an example of a *full* path? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20705816/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

**From future:**

dx tool was replaced by d8 with several improvements, it can be found at

```
build-tools/{{version}}/d8
```

For more information about dx to d8 transition visit [next link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/the-path-to-dx-deprecation.html)